# How to reuse use SAS output in other procedures

Tags: sas, export, ods

How do I use the output variable of one PROC into another PROC. 
I'm new to SAS and have spend many hours trying to solve this problem in the program below.

```
 DATA FA2;    
 SET FA2;    
 proc iml;    
 start main;    
 use FA2;    
 read all var {Close};    
 s = Close;    
 u = j(nrow(s)-1,1,0);    
 do i=2 to nrow(s);    
 u[i-1]=log(s[i]/s[i-1]);    
 end;    
 n=nrow(s)-1;    
 rsigma=sqrt(252/n*(u'*u));    
 mu = mean(u);    
 call qntl(q, u);    
 print q[rowname={"P05", "P95"}];    
 s = quartile(u);    
 PRINT mu, rsigma, s;    
 finish;    
 run;    
 PROC UNIVARIATE DATA = FA2;
 var u;
 run;


 ERROR    
 PROC UNIVARIATE DATA = FA2;    
 var u;    
 Variable U not found.    
 run;
```

Comment: Can you please comment your code to indicate what you think it's doing? That code is garbled and isn't correct, but without understanding what you're trying to accomplish it's hard to say what you should be doing.

Comment: Does not look like you ever saved the results of your matrix manipulations back out into any SAS datasets for the PROC to access.

Comment: @Tom - yes I know that is what I am trying to find out, how to save the result into a SAS dataset from where I can use it repeatedly

Comment: @Reeza - The code works fine, except the univariate part. I'm calculating log returns and performing financial calculations on NASDAQ100 index.

Comment: @rakesh, code working does not mean it's correct. For example the first two lines do absolutely nothing, you don't have a RUN step to terminate and we're guessing at what you're trying to do.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. As I'm new I don't know a lot but I'll learn fast. Thanks for taking the time to look into my problem. I really appreciate it

Comment: Comment your code then, if you want to learn fast. It doesn't slow you down in the long run, it actually speeds it up because it reduces confusion.

Comment: @Tom Thanks a lot Tom, I searched google for "matrix manipulations into SAS datasets " and got the answer.All this time I was using wrong questions to find the solution.

Comment: @Reeza- Sure. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Your first two lines accomplish nothing and are not useful - remove them.

   ```
   data fa2;
   set fa2;
   ```
2. You are not creating any output data set within the IML statement, and you really shouldn't reuse the same data set name (FA2) so many times. It makes it harder to debug your code.  See the example below.

   ```
      proc iml;
   /** create SAS data set from vectors **/
   y = {1,0,3,2,0,3}; /** 6 x 1 vector **/
   z = {8,7,6,5,6};   /** 5 x 1 vector **/
   c = {A A A B B B}; /** 1 x 6 character vector **/

   create MyData var {y z c}; /** create data set **/
   append;       /** write data in vectors **/
   close MyData; /** close the data set **/
   quit;
   ```
3. IML ends with a `QUIT;` at the end.
4. PROC UNIVARIATE is referencing your FA2 data set which does not have U, because you did not save the variable to the data set so it doesn't exist. So it is correctly generating an error. Fixing the above issues should resolve this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your insightful answer and advice. I solved my problem.